# Facebook Like Button on different .asp "Item" pages

Tags: facebook, button, asp-classic, facebook-like

Please bear with me, I have bought an "Off the shelf" application Classifieds Application written in Classic ASP.

I have completely re-styled it all myself whilst learning the code.

I am now wanting to get the Facebook Like button to "Like" individual Items.  The following code is the actual like button code

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.worthingads.com/Classifieds/CPViewItem.asp?ID=<%=request("ID")%>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I have "replace" functions on the asp page as below

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "%TITLE%", sItemTitle)
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "%IMAGE%", sImage)
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "%DESCRIPTION%", sCadDescription)
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "%URL%", sURL)
```

And I have the Meta OG on the HTML Template (which surrounds that asp page as below

```
<meta property="og:title" content="%TITLE%"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="ARTICLE"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="%URL%"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="%IMAGE%"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="WorthingAds.com"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="%DESCRIPTION%"/>
```

If I place the "placeholders" of %TITLE% into the HTML page it will show the Title of the item and so on but, once the item is liked, Facebook doesn't show the items proper details if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You should run your page URL thru the Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to check your meta tags are working correctly and returning the right data.

Comment: Thanks Barry - I will do but not sure what the results mean lol

Comment: Essentially it will show you what data Facebook can pull from the page and should help solve the problem. As if Facebook is not showing the proper details then the debugger will show you what Facebook is loading from you.